# push_back keeps rewriting all entries in the vector to the item pushed_back?

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop, vector

I am currently trying to make a light copy of a `vector`. A light copy meaning that the content of the copy, is a `vector` of pointer of the original `vector`.  I am for some reasons having problems doing so... Each time I `push_back` a new entry into the copy `vector`, I seem to overwrite all the entries in the `vector`, to the element I just `push_back`, why is this happening:

MWE:

```
// This file is a "Hello, world!" in C++ language by GCC for wandbox.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


struct abstract_data_structure
{
    int x;
    int y;
    std::vector<int> points;
    std::string name;

    abstract_data_structure(int x, int y , std::vector<int> points, std::string name)
    {
        this->x= x;
        this->y = y;
        this->points = points;
        this->name = name;
    }
};

int main()
{
     std::vector<abstract_data_structure> storage;
     std::vector<abstract_data_structure*> copy_of_storage;

     std::srand(std::time(0));
     for (int i = 0; i< 5 ; i++)
     {     
        int x = std::rand();
        int y = std::rand();
        std::vector<int> vecOfRandomNums(10);
        std::generate(vecOfRandomNums.begin(), vecOfRandomNums.end(), []() {
           return rand() % 100;
        });
        std::string name = "something"+std::to_string(i);
        abstract_data_structure something(x,y,vecOfRandomNums,name);
        storage.push_back(something);

     }

    std::cout << storage.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Make the copy" << std::endl;

    for (auto element : storage)
    {
        std::cout << "in storage" << std::endl;
        std::cout << element.name << std::endl;
        copy_of_storage.push_back(&(element));
        std::cout << "in copy storage" << std::endl; 

        for (auto copy_element: copy_of_storage)
        {
            std::cout << copy_element->name << std::endl; 
        }
    }


}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/Xn96xbIshd6RXTRa

which outputs this:

```
5
Make the copy
in storage
something0
in copy storage
something0
in storage
something1
in copy storage
something1
something1
in storage
something2
in copy storage
something2
something2
something2
in storage
something3
in copy storage
something3
something3
something3
something3
in storage
something4
in copy storage
something4
something4
something4
something4
something4
0
```

As one might see are all the entries in the copy vector, modified to point to last element inserted? why?

Comment: `for (auto element : storage)` -> `for (auto& element : storage)`

Comment: Thanks... Why doesn't it affect copy_storage?

Comment: `copy_of_storage.push_back(&(element));` is currently pushing back the address of an Automatic variable that goes out of scope at the end of loop iteration. Using pointers to invalid data has unpredictable results.

Comment: Any suggestions to remedy this? @user4581301... I seem to be able to print the content out outside the loop?

Comment: Hard to suggest anything. If you do that @Justin suggests, you'll get your expected behaviour, but you WON'T get a copy. With pointers you get a reference to an exiting object, not a copy of it. On the other hand, if you drop the pointer (`std::vector<abstract_data_structure> copy_of_storage;`) and instead `copy_of_storage.push_back(element);`  then you will have copies.

Comment: "I seem to be able to print the content out outside the loop?" unfortunately the unpredictable results include everything from the program crashing to the outright fantastic. In the middle somewhere you get the utterly horrible "It looks like it works." With a crash or Elves dancing on your keyboard, you know something is wrong, but the only way to tell that something looking right is actually wrong is with careful inspection. Or in the aftermath of the Autopilot steering the jumbo jet into the side of a mountain because the computed course was actually out by a tenth of a degree.

Comment: yes.. @user4581301 you are right in the given example are they not the same..

Comment: would it help if they were contained within a class..? 
as the case I am currently working has both variable in same class, and the test shows that their content are the same..

Comment: @salam -- Even if you were to accomplish your goal, it isn't a good idea to grab and hold onto pointers to elements within a vector.  If that vector is resized in any way, those pointers become invalidated.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes.. you are right... didn't think of that.. 
are there any alternatives to shallow vector copies?

Comment: @salam Well, `std::list` doesn't invalidate elements when resized (unless the element is removed).  But I don't know if that meets your requirements wrt vector (contiguous properties, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//***1***
for (auto element : storage)
{
    std::cout << "in storage" << std::endl;
    std::cout << element.name << std::endl;
    //***2***
    copy_of_storage.push_back(&(element));
    std::cout << "in copy storage" << std::endl; 

    for (auto copy_element: copy_of_storage)
    {
        std::cout << copy_element->name << std::endl; 
    }
}
```

At `***1***`, you're making a local copy of each variable.

At `***2***`, you're taking the address of that local copy and saving it in the vector.

When you leave scope, the object has been destructed and no longer exists. So when you later try to read it, you get **Undefined Behavior**, which means you cannot guarantee the behavior that will take place.

What *seems* to be happening is that each time, you're taking the address of the local variable, and each iteration of the for-loop, that location of the variable is the same, so each address in the final copy vector is the same, and because the most recent copy is whichever entry in the `storage` vector you were most recently working with, that's the version that gets read by the pointer.

If you change `***1***` to `for(auto & element : storage)`, your issue should be fixed.

Comment: Not the downvoter, But is the issue fixed? The asker did not make a copy, and if anything triggers a resize of the source `vector`, cometh the nasal demons.

Comment: @user4581301 The OP said in their original post "*I am currently trying to make a light copy of a vector. A light copy meaning that the content of the copy, is a vector of pointer of the original vector.*". This code does exactly what they asked, and solves the problem with their code which was attempting to do that. It's not my place to tell the user they *shouldn't* be trying to do this unless they clearly have an XY-Problem, which it isn't clear they do.

Comment: You have raisins, as the French say.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a bit deeper than you may suspect. In

```
std::vector<abstract_data_structure> storage;
std::vector<abstract_data_structure*> copy_of_storage;
```

`copy_of_storage` cannot be a copy of `storage` without a lot of extra effort and probably dynamic allocation of `abstract_data_structure`s.

`copy_of_storage` contains pointers and those pointers have to point to `abstract_data_structure`s. These `abstract_data_structure`s may or may not be copies.

The naive fix, swapping

```
for (auto element : storage)
```

for

```
for (auto & element : storage)
```

makes element a reference to an `abstract_data_structure` stored within `storage`. This means that `element` references a variable that has longer life than a single iteration of the for loop, but

```
copy_of_storage.push_back(&(element));
```

doesn't make a copy. It just points to the original `abstract_data_structure` inside `storage`. Sometimes this is useful, but when one list is supposed to be a copy of the other, it probably should directly refer to the other list.

For example, adding another `abstract_data_structure` to `storage` will invalidate the pointers. The contents of `storage` can be moved in the existing storage. The storage may be replaced with a larger block and the pointers left pointing to invalid memory. All sorts of nasty things can happen.

Instead, I recommend

```
std::vector<abstract_data_structure> storage;
std::vector<abstract_data_structure> copy_of_storage;
```

and later

```
for (auto & element : storage)
```

and

```
copy_of_storage.push_back(element);
```

Now you have a copy.

But... there are easier ways. `std::vector` is a very smart beast. You can

```
copy_of_storage = storage;
```

and `storage` will copy itself.

Recommended extra reading: [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) This is not required for your example, but very very important to learn early in a programming career.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations... And to elaborate a bit on the copy, the idea to have a copy_vector was so it would not be memory heavy as the first one,  and to have a vector in which I can change the order of the elements in the vector without actually messing with the way is it stored in storage (The order is important).. My intention was to sort the copy_vector and do some matching, and see which one  the test matches best, and output the name given.

Comment: In that case, so long as you are careful about the contents of `storage` (build it and don't change it with also regenerating `copy_of_storage`, go with Xirema's answer.